# Spark-submit fails with yarn master, error- requirement failed at scala.Predef

Tags: apache-spark, mapr, sparkcore

My Spark job is failing with below exception and I am not able to figureout what requirement is missing which causing job failure:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Client.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Client.scala:470)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6.apply(Client.scala:470)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6.apply(Client.scala:468)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:468)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:727)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1021)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:742)
```

**Spark-submit command:**

```
spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/xyz/conf/log4j.xml \
-DHOME=/xyz/transformation -DENV=e1 \
-DJOB=xformation --conf spark.local.dir=/warehouse/tmp/spark1489619325 \
--queue dev --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
--properties-file /xyz/conf/job.conf \
--files /xyz/conf/e1.properties --class TransformationJob /xyz/job.jar
```

The same program works fine with master as local.

Any suggestions would be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to enclose your --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions parameters within double quotes ?

Comment: yes..  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a huge list of jars in classpath using '--jars' element and one of the jar was culprit, when I remove it from '--jars' the issue got resolved, I am still not sure why spark-submit was failing because of that jar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error caused by the data file.
I pointed to the wrong train data direction.

Train data and test data did not match well.

Train data: `0,1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1`

Test data: `1, 2, 0, 0, 10`

I fixed the train data source direction and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

I received a similar error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$8$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Client.scala:501)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$8$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Client.scala:499)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$8.apply(Client.scala:499)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$8.apply(Client.scala:497)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:763)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**Solution to this is :**

On the terminal or log you will have one WARN line as below :

**WARN Client: Resource file: added multiple times to distributed cache.**

Just delete this extra jar from spark submit script . Hope this will help all .